# Why I can't apply changes to prefab even if there are no errors?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I changed on character prefab I dragged to the Hierarchy on the Animator Controller I changed the Update Mode to Animate Physics but the Apply All button is grayed.

[image: Grayed out]

When I select the Prefab Asset I can't see any problems in the Rig or Animation tabs.

[image: Prefab Asset]

There are no errors or warnings about it in the console.

Comment: Did you try it directly in the Prefab editor (double click on Prefab)? Might be something about multiscene editing?

Comment: @derHugo Not sure but I did now right click in the Hierarchy and then Unpack Prefab Completely and now it changed the prefab in the Hierarchy to a regular object like a regular gameobject now I can change stuff without need to apply so it's fine.

Comment: @derHugo In my screenshot in the Hierarchy the dragged prefab there was something small white on it I wonder what it was ?

Comment: It seems that the prefab is a model prefab : https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.formats.fbx@2.0/manual/prefabs.html

Comment: Yes possible that this was the case and yep in this case you have to unpack everything you want to be able to change .. it is easier to differ between the prefab types of you scroll out in the Assets View so you can see only the file names and icons ;)